# Why is `subprocess.call` not invoking the command

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying to run a .wav file through ffmpeg using the `subprocess.call(shell=True)` in the following code and it doesn't seem to run. I know this because the `output_file` isn't created and I'm getting an exception in the `open()` method.
What am I doing wrong?

```
try:
    import pocketsphinx

except:
    import pocketsphinx as ps
    import sphinxbase
    import subprocess
    import os

hmmd = "../../Pocketsphinx_Files/en-us-8khz"
lmdir = "../../Pocketsphinx_Files/cmusphinx-5.0-en-us.lm"
dictp = "../../Pocketsphinx_Files/cmu07a.dic"

output_filename = "../../temp/ps_output.wav"

def recognize(filename="../../temp/temp_output.wav"):

    command = "ffmpeg -i "+filename+" -ac 1 -ab 16 -ar 16000 "+output_filename

    subprocess.call(command,shell=True)

    wavFile = open(output_filename,"rb")

    speechRec = ps.Decoder(hmm = hmmd, lm = lmdir, dict = dictp)

    wavFile.seek(44)

    speechRec.decode_raw(wavFile)

    result = speechRec.get_hyp()

    #os.remove(filename)
    #os.remove(output_filename)

    return result

if __name__=="__main__":
    print(recognize())
```

edit: I've got ffmpeg installed.
Furthermore, when I run the subprocess.call() command from the python interpreter it seems to work. This is why I'm stumped.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Mac running OSX. ffmpeg seems to working using the terminal

Comment: Try making ```command``` a list.  According to the docs, ```"Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments "```

Comment: You're also using relative paths. Unless you're very sure of what ``cwd`` is going to be when you run this, those paths might not evaluate correctly.

Comment: Do your paths contain spaces at all? You are building a string that shell will parse; either properly quote your filenames, or better yet, *don't use `shell=True` and pass in a list of arguments*.

Comment: @wnnmaw - I've tried that using `command.split()` and removing the `shell=True`. I'm now getting a `child_exception`
@aruisdante - How can I make sure I am at the right one? 
Either way, I've tried replacing both paths with the absolute one and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you try using `subprocess.check_call()` or `check_output` instead of simply `call`. They will raise an exception if your program fails to execute correctly, instead of leaving you wondering why no output was generated.

I'm going to guess that you may somehow be having path issues with your executable in a Python environment

Try using this function with 'ffmpeg':

```
def is_exe(prog):
    for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, prog)):
            if os.access(os.path.join(path, prog), os.X_OK):
                return os.path.join(path, prog)
            else:
                print "Program '%s' found in '%s', but lacks executable permissions." % (prog, path)
    return False
```

If it returns `False`, you're having problems with Python running ffmpeg, otherwise it's ffmpeg which is having problems making sense of your arguments.

Comment: It's returning false. And the check_all() method returns error code 127 which is `command not found`. Why is that? I have it installed and like I said in the post it executes correctly when I run it from the interpreter

Comment: That would seem to confirm that the PATH under Python is different from your terminal one, and it can't find ffmpeg. You can compare them both with `echo $PATH` on the terminal and `print os.environ["PATH"]` from Python. The directory containing ffmpeg will most likely be missing from the latter. Once you know what the path for ffmpeg is (you may also be able to find that using `which ffmpeg`, although I don't know if OS X has that), you can either specify the full path for your command or add it to Python's PATH environment variable.

Comment: How come when I run the `os.environ["PATH"]` in the python interpreter and when I print it in my program I get two different outputs? The interpreter one is the same as `echo $PATH` while the latter is not.

Comment: How are you running the script? Is it from the terminal, i.e. `python yourscript.py` or from the GUI by double-clicking it? When you you log into the terminal you're typically importing a bunch of environment variables (from your .bashrc file, for instance, among others) which don't otherwise get imported from executing Python alone.

Comment: I'm running it through my IDE. But your answer still makes sense. Thanks!